# Variable is exceeding specified limit in for loop

Tags: c

I have written code to find the units and tens digit of a number,but am facing a problem when the number is greater than 99.The value of i has been set to less than 10 inside the for loop but when i execute the code with `no=100`,I find that i has a value of 10.

Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int unit(int x){
  return x%10;
}

int ten(int x){
  int temp=x-unit(x);
  if(temp==0){
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        if(temp%(i*10)==0 && temp/(i*10)==1){
            return i;

        }
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  int no=100;
  printf("%d",ten((no)));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. For example I do not understand this phrase "code to find the units and tens digit" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what happens when the number is greater than 99. You will not be able to find a value of i b/w 1 and 9 such that the expression in the if is true. You will need a value of i > 10, but of course, then it wouldn't be the tens digit of the number.

Your method only works for a specific case, ie, when the number is b/w 1 and 10^2. Sure, you could write some more code to make it work for numbers b/w  1 and 10^3, but that would just be a pain in the ass. Even then, you'd have to write more code if the number is greater than that.

Try to think of a solution for the general case. To do that, two facts would be very useful:

1. Dividing using / only gives the integer part of the answer. Eg: 66/10 = 6
2. % This operator gives you the remainder. Eg: 59%10 = 9

Answer (score 0):

1) In the `else` block of `ten()` you are returning a value only if some condition is met. If the condition does not satisfy you are not returning anything. In that case a garbage value may be printed.

2) To get the tenth digit, that is a lot of work. Just change the function body to -

```
int ten(int x) {
 return (x % 100) /10;
}
```

The numbers upto 99 gets correct result because the condition satisfies. Lets take 99 as an example. After unit digit subtraction you got 90. When `i` becomes 9, the `temp%(i*10)` becomes 0 and `temp/(i*10)` becomes 1.

When number is 100, after unit digit subtraction the number remains same(i.e. 100). But for values of `i`  from 1 to 9 `temp/(i*10)` never becomes 1 and the loop quits, resulting in the absurd behavior. You will get the same behavior for all the numbers that are greater than 99 using your code.